# Show image captions inside the_content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I read the post content within my own Wordpress theme using the_content(). How do I achieve that the images within the content are output with captions? Preferably without a plugin, directly via the loop or the functions.php.

(The media are already provided with titles, etc.)

Comment: Are you need only images form the content?

Comment: Yes, at the moment. I was able to solve it for the featured image, but not for the the_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images in the post/page content which have captions are automatically output as `figure` elements including the caption, see the official docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/media/images/#caption

Comment: Your hint led me to the cause of the problem. I had filled in "title" instead of "caption". Is it possible to output the title instead of the caption?

Comment: AFAIK no, at least not without a plugin or a similar hook.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
       $beforeEachImage = "<div>";
       $afterEachImage = "</div>";
       preg_match_all("/(<img [^>]*>)/",get_the_content(),$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
       for( $i=0; isset($matches[1]) && $i < count($matches[1]); $i++ ) {
             echo $beforeEachImage . $matches[1][$i] . $afterEachImage;
       }
    ?>
```

**Use this code for get images.**